# Action delegate in .NET2 - Using the generic type 'System.Action<T>' requires '1' type arguments

Tags: c#, delegates

I'm porting working code from .NET4 to .NET2 (a WinCE device).

The usage of Action taking no arguments and returning no value isn't allowed in .NET2

compile error on line 5 below: Using the generic type 'System.Action' requires '1' type arguments

Workaround thoughts?

```
//first state is the default for the system
    public enum States { EnterVoucherCode, EnterTotalSale, ProcessVoucher };
    public enum Events { PressNext, PressRedeem, ProcessSuccess, ProcessFail, PressBackToVoucherCode };

    public States State { get; set; }

    private Action[,] fsm; //Fails to compile here

    public FiniteStateMachine()
    {
        //array of action delegates
        fsm = new Action[3, 5] { 
        //PressNext,     PressRedeem,            ProcessSuccess,      ProcessFail,      PressBackToVoucherCode
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Indeed, the non-generic `Action` was added in .NET 3.5.

However, `Action` is just an ordinary delegate type, so you could simply roll your own, like so:

```
public delegate void Action();
```

Comment: This Help me! Thank You!
I have convert a project to NET6 and use a NET2 linephone in this, the compiler
has no error on  "void SetTimeout (Action callback, int miliseconds) " after i add the
public delegate void Action();