# Using the generic type 'State<T>' requires 1 type arguments C#

Tags: c#, generics, delegates

I am new in c# and I am trying to generate a class that's using templates, generic type for one of its arguments.

```
class State<T>
{

    private T state;         // the state represented by a string
    private double cost;     // cost to reach this state (set by a setter)
    private State cameFrom;  // the state we came from to this state
```

I get the following error:

```
Using the generic type 'State<T>' requires 1 type arguments
```

I've found this [Action delegate in .NET2 - Using the generic type 'System.Action<T>' requires '1' type arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8263626/action-delegate-in-net2-using-the-generic-type-system-actiont-requires-1)
but it's not my case..
since I'm new in c# i haven't added any code to the regular c-sharp libraries.

HELP.?

Comment: You should declare `private State<T> cameFrom;` instead of `private State cameFrom;`

Comment: Your comment reads "the state represented by a string", but this suggests `state` should be of type `string`, at which point you can simply make the class non-generic. How are you actually using `T`? What does it mean for your class? Depending on that meaning, @Valentin's comment *may* be an appropriate fix, but for other possible meanings, it may be completely wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you don't have a `State` class, you have a generic class `State<T>`.

So you should declare `private State<T> cameFrom;` instead of `private State cameFrom;`